# nginx rewrite rule for search and replace?

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, server

I want to add rewrite rule on Nginx server

To search the specific number or word on every page before loading it
and replacing it:

```
search ;someword; replace with ;13123123; 

my server Nginx+php-fpm-varnish
```

Comment: are we talking about content replace? or url replace?

Answer (score 0):

You could check nginx [`sub_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter)

```
sub_filter ';someword;' ';13123123;' ;
```

Comment: thanks i try code but nginx: [emerg] directive "sub_filter" is not terminated by ";" in      are there any example to use it

Comment: sorry mohammed i try to learning :) can you give me example to replace number. on page to another i cant write the right syntax

Comment: this number in 
<ins class="line" style="display:inline-block" data="**123**" data-slot="878787878">
i want to change 123 to other no

Comment: the error is just like it said, i forgot to add the semi colon, ill fix my answer

Comment: the problem with generic stuff is that it could happen in the wrong places, like if i said replace 1 with 2, 11 will become 22 and 15 will become 25, see the problem? in your question you used `;someword;` with two semi colons, so i thought maybe you did that on purpose to make the word unique.

Comment: the no in data="123"  will be very unique

can you give me example how i can do it ?

Comment: the first quoted string is the string you want to replace and the second quoted string is that you want to replace it with, I've used the exact example you mentioned in your question in my answer.